# Stop program from running as admin

Tags: windows-10, uac

I have a program that runs with elevated privileges when I double click on the icon(Task Manger shows Elevated = Yes).  I do not want it to run with elevated privileges but I have not been able to figure out how to turn it off.

I checked the following places:

1.)Right Click on the shortcut -> Advanced -> Run as admin is unchecked

2.)Right Click on the shortcut -> Compatibility -> Run as admin is unchecked

3.)Right Click on the exe -> Compatibility -> Run as admin is unchecked

I've tried the following commands:

1.)runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "newapp.exe"

2.)runas /user:domain\username "newapp.exe"

No matter what I do or check the app still runs with elevated privileges.  Any ideas on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio, use "Open a file..." on the exe. Select the ``RT_MANIFEST`` text block, and paste it into notepad. You can then see if it has a UAC manifest marked as "requireAdministrator".

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Where is the "Open a file..." option that you are talking about?

Comment: Did you write this program or does this question belong on SuperUser?

Comment: @Anders I did not write this program.  This program was written by Sybase/Appeon.  So should I move this to SuperUser?

Comment: This seems like some kind of developer tool? It is up to you if you want to move it I guess, SU is unlikely to provide a better answer. Either way, your best bet is to actually ask the author...

Comment: @Anders  OK,  I will check with them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 4 reasons why Windows might decide to [UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works) elevate a new process.

- [`requestedExecutionLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)) in the [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) is set to `requireAdministrator` or `highestAvailable`.
- Installer detection.
- The compatibility tab for the shortcut or .exe has set certain properties (run as Windows XP etc.)
- `ShellExecute` was invoked with the `RunAs` verb.

The application manifest is embedded in the .exe or in a file next to it named "applicationname.exe.manifest". You can explore the embedded manifest with a tool like [Manifest View](https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/manifest-view-1-0) or [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

If you did not write the application yourself, do you actually know if it will even work if not elevated? You can try to [force it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161117-00/?p=94735) in cmd.exe:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
c:\path\theapp.exe
```

Comment: For more on Win32 exe manifests, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/).

Comment: @Anders  Here is the ouput from the tool:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" name="Sybase.PB" type="win32" /> 
  <description>PowerBuilder Manifest</description> 
- <dependency>
- <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" /> 
  </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  </assembly>